# Errors with apt-get update

Tags: apt, 18.04

It looks like other people have had similar issues and I tried to do what people were advising, but it didn't work.

[image: the log]

Edit: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` returns `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: I tried that but I got a message that I couldn't post that many links

Comment: [Enable universe](https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/480481) and install `ppa-purge` first by running `sudo apt install ppa-purge`.

Comment: still getting the same error messages

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- Safest - remove all the PPAs that are erroring

  - Use either `ppa-purge` or Software & Updates
- Risky - launch Software & Updates > Other Software > clicking on the erroring PPAs > Edit... > change Distribution to one that the PPA has packages for. You could search for the PPA in Google to find the Launchpad page to check which Ubuntu version the PPA has packages for

  - Note that this is much more risky because the PPA creator didn't at all test installing to 18.04, you could potentially break your system (which you run the risk of doing anyway with PPAs - they're not packages tested with normal Ubuntu quality processes to work on Ubuntu and with Ubuntu updates)